# Vector product problem

Tags: vectors

Source:

University Physics with Modern Physics (15th ed.)

Chapter 1 - Units, Physical Quantities and Vectors

Exercises - Section 1.10 Product of Vectors

Question 1.47:

The vector product of vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ has magnitude 16.0 $m^2$ and is in the +z direction. If vector $\vec A$ has magnitude 8.0m and is in the -x direction, what are the magnitude and direction of vector $\vec B$ if it has no x-component?

The answer supplied at the back of the book is -2.0m and -x direction.

Can someone explain how we arrive at these answers? I have had a few attempts, but I must be missing something.

Comment: Answer seems wrong. Magnitude $2.0$m (always positive) in the $-y$ (negative $y$) direction.

Comment: This is why your first exposure to vector algebra shouldn't be in physics class.

Comment: Thank god this is the consensus. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: @DougM That really depends on the quality (rigour) of the Physics text and the motivation of the student to look up pure math texts to fill in the gaps.

Comment: @Deepak I was being just a little sarcastic with my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector product (or cross product) is an operation on two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ that returns a vector in $\mathbb R^3$

The result will be perpendicular (or orthogonal) to the two vectors you multiply.

If you experiment using your fingers or pencils or similar to represent two vectors that touch at their tails, these two vectors lie in some plane.  A vector that is perpendicular to both and perpendicular to the plane they lie in.

You might note that this vector can point in two different directions.  For example, if you have two vectors in a plane that is parallel to the floor, your resultant vector could point up or it could point down.  Changing the order of multiplication swaps the direction that the resulting vector points.

$\mathbf u \times \mathbf v = - (\mathbf v\times \mathbf u)$

The vector product is anti-symmetric.

So which direction does the cross-product point?  The direction is determined by "the right-hand rule."  This rule is somewhat arbitrary, but we need a rule and right is as good as left.  To apply the right-hand rule, hold your right hand out with your palm open, thumb extended, and fingers pointing toward the first vector.  Close your hand until your fingers are pointing toward the second vector.  Your thumb points in the direction of the resulting vector.

The magnitude of the resulting vector is equal to the area of the parallelogram with vertexes at $\mathbf 0, \mathbf u, \mathbf v, \mathbf u+\mathbf v$  You can express this area as $\|\mathbf u\|\|\mathbf v\|\sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$

With vectors in Cartesian form, one method to calculate the cross product.

$(u_x, u_y, u_z)\times(v_x, v_y, v_z) = \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf i & \mathbf j &\mathbf k\\ u_x &u_y&u_z \\ v_x&v_y&v_z\end{bmatrix}\right)$

It is worth noting that the cross-product is only defined in 3-dimensional space.  It does not extend into higher dimensions.

To the problem at hand.

$\|A\times B\| = 16$
$A\times B$ points in the $z$ direction.
$\|A\| = 8$
$A$ points in the $-x$ direction.
$B$ has $0$ component in the $x$ direction.

One way to set this up is to give these vectors coordinates.

$A\times B = (0,0,16)\\
A = (-8,0,0)\\
B = (0,y,0)$

$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf i & \mathbf j &\mathbf k\\ -8 &0&0 \\ 0&y&0\end{bmatrix}\right) = (0,0,-8y) = (0,0,16)$

$y = -2\\
B = (0,-2,0)$

Another way would be to say that if $B$ has no $x$ component, $B$ must be perpendicular to $A,$ and $\sin \theta = 1.$  This means that since $\|A\|\|B\|\sin\theta = 16$ then  $\|B\| =2$

Then we place the fingers of our right hand pointing in the $-x$ direction on our page, with thumb pointing out of the page.  We close our fingers until they align with the $y$ axis.  Are they pointing toward $y$ or $-y$?

While a bit long-winded, I hope this background helps.